# Angular2 Get component reference dynamically

Tags: javascript, angular

I have multiple `<mat-button-toggle>` elements generated in my app and I want always only one selected. The problem that I now have is, how to get the component reference to the last selected toggle-button when another toggle button is clicked.

I really searched quite a while but couldn't understand how to do it.

#### component.html

```
<mat-button-toggle (click)="onKeywordSelect($event)" *ngFor="let keyword of keywords" [id]="keyword.id" [attr.id]="keyword.id" [value]="keyword.id" class="keyword">
  <div class="text">{{ keyword.name }}</div>
</mat-button-toggle>
```

#### component.ts

```
// imports and @Component

export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

  keywords = [new Keyword('name1'), new Keyword('name2')]; // sample data
  $selectedKeyword: $ | any; // I've imported JQuery

  onKeywordSelect(event: any) {
    // This element depends on where you mouse was positioned when clicking
    // Most often not the <mat-button-toggle> but some child element
    const target = event.target;
    // To get to the <mat-button-toggle> component that was clicked
    const matButton = $(target).closest('mat-button-toggle');

    if (this.$selectedKeyword !== undefined) {
        // At the start there is no selected keyword
        // TODO: Set the 'checked' property of the cur selected keyword to false
    }
    this.$selectedKeyword = $matButton;
  }
}
```

I tried it with [@ViewChild()](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) but because the `id` of the selected keyword changes when the user selects one I don't know how to keep track of the selected component reference.

## Edit

Forgot to mention: Yes I'm aware of `mat-button-toggle-group` but I don't want to use it because of some styling. Is there no other way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** Updated my ans as your requirement is not to use `mat-button-toggle-group`:

You can use `checked` property and set current and last selected value on `change` event like this:

**component.html:**

```
<mat-button-toggle
  *ngFor="let keyword of keywords"
  value="{{keyword.id}}"
  [id]="keyword.id"
  [attr.id]="keyword.id"
  (change)="this.onChange(keyword.id)"
  [checked]="this.currValue === keyword.id">
  {{keyword.name}}
</mat-button-toggle>

<div class="example-selected-value">
    Last Selected value: {{this.lastValue}}
</div>
<div class="example-selected-value">
    Current Selected value: {{this.currValue}}
</div>
```

**component.ts:**

```
keywords: any = [
    {id: 1, name: "name1"},
    {id: 2, name: "name2"},
    {id: 3, name: "name3"},
  ]
  lastValue: string = "";
  currValue: string = "";

  onChange = (value) => {
    this.lastValue = this.currValue;
    this.currValue = value;
  }
```

Check Demo [**Here**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-toggle-5ozexu?file=app/button-toggle-exclusive-example.ts).

Comment: Thanks! Works great. Didn't think of that.

Answer (score 0):

```html
Add mat-button-toggle-group to select only one button and get value of group to get last selected button 

see: https://stackblitz.com/angular/yrqebgjbxao?file=app%2Fbutton-toggle-exclusive-example.ts
```

Comment: I already know about `mat-button-toggle-group`, but I'm trying to achieve this effect without wrapping the buttons in this element.

Comment: you can use name(to select only single button) & form controller(to get value)  <mat-button-toggle  name="yourName" formControlName=controller (click)="onKeywordSelect($event)" *ngFor="let keyword of keywords" [id]="keyword.id" [attr.id]="keyword.id" [value]="keyword.id" class="keyword">
  <div class="text">{{ keyword.name }}</div>
</mat-button-toggle>